# Are there any vegan chocolate spreads which taste like Nutella available in the UK?

Tags: veganism, food, substitutes, dairy-substitutes, uk

I am looking for a vegan chocolate spread that tastes similiarly to Nutella which would be available in the UK. I am open to some differences in taste, but I would ideally want something with comparable level of sweetness as Nutella has. Product can be available only online, but it should ship across the UK without expensive delivery charges.

Sustainable ingredients or those that avoid hydrogenated or saturated fat would be a plus.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sub>click the pictures to go to a UK-based online supplier.</sub>

#### Mr Organic Free From Chocolate Hazelnut Spread (cheapest & most like Nutella)

[image: Mr Organic Free From Chocolate Hazelnut Spread]

Ingredients: Cane sugar, sunflower oil, Cocoa (16%), Hazelnut paste (12%), Rice Flour, Cocoa butter, Sunflower Lecithin

Also available in independent health food stores

---

#### Rawtella (sweetened with supersweet coconut blosson nectar)

[image: Rawtella]

Ingredients: Hazelnuts, coconut palm sugar, cacao powder, cashew nuts, vanilla, salt.

---

#### Seggiano Smooth Dark Chocolate Organic Hazelnut Spread (less sweet)

[image: Seggiano Smooth Dark Chocolate Organic Hazelnut Spread]

Ingredients: Hazelnut paste* 35%, cane sugar*, low fat cocoa powder* 19%, sunflower oil*, cocoa butter*, sunflower lecithin*. *organic ingredient

Also available in Planet Organic London and other independent health food stores

Answer (score 3):

Solkiki (in Dorset) is owned and operated by Iris and Bob, both vegans. Everything they make is vegan. It's also ethically sourced and award-winning. They are a real treasure.

They make a Hazelnut Chocolate Spread and a bar with the flavor profile you're asking about:

Spread at [Hazelnut Chocolate Spread](https://www.solkiki.co.uk/product-page/bean-to-jar-hazelnut-chocolate-spread)

Bar at
[35% Hazelnut Cream - White Gianduja with Piedmont Hazelnuts](https://www.solkiki.co.uk/product-page/white-hazelnut-gianduja-white-chocolate)

So, Solkiki is just about the best place to find artisan, always vegan, bean-to-bar (not industrial) chocolate and is dedicated to doing good in the world and making your taste buds happy. I also think they are flavor wizards who are exceptionally creative.